# Transfer function of circuit composed of resistors and capacitors

Tags: transfer-function

It has been said that $$V_{\text{out}} = \frac{V_{\text{a}}}{2}$$
I'm not sure why this would be.
Could someone please tell me why?

[image]

Comment: Because the impedances form a voltage divider.

Comment: And just what exactly would have you believe that half of the impedances are present at node Va?

Comment: What exactly does that mean "half of the impedances are present at node Va?" Assuming no load at Vout, it is very obvious that Vout = Va / 2 because the two capacitors of the same value (C) form a voltage divider that cuts the input (Va) in half.

Comment: It would be preferable if  you had the signal flowing from left to right, as is convention.

Answer (score 1):

At any frequency, the impedance offered by those two capacitors will be same (because both have same capacitance). Since same current flows through them, the voltage drop across them will also be the same = Va/2.

Comment: The only two components with the same current flowing through them is the capacitor and resistor in series near Vin

Comment: these two rail systems confuse me a bit but after converting it into a single line i understand now.

i.e. vin-------C1------VOUT--------C2--ground

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to not be confused by things like this?

Comment: by vin above i actually mean Va by the way

Comment: @gorge same current flows through \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$. At node Va, this splits into two. \$V_a/R_2\$ flows to ground through the resistor and \$V_a/(\frac{1}{jwC} + \frac{1}{jwC}) \$ flows through the capacitors \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$ (left most).

Comment: @gorge I didn't get the conersion you did.

Comment: Va flows into the capacitor immediately to the left of node Va. The next node after that capacitor is where the voltage is being measured with respect to ground which is why my conversion works.